# Jquery Shortening code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive posted a similar question before, yet again i find my self stupidly copy and pasting code.

is there anyway i can combine the following, im sure there is.. Please help.. Im in the learning process.

See i have the follow:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input.email', function() {
    validate_Email_Input(this);
});

$(document).on('blur', 'input.id', function() {
    validate_Id_Input(this);
});

$(document).on('blur', 'input.pass', function() {
    validate_Pass_Input(this);
});

$(document).on('blur', 'input.town', function() {
    validate_Town_Input(this);
});

$(document).on('blur', 'input.relation', function() {
    validate_Relation_Input(this);
});

$(document).on('blur', 'input.contact', function() {
    validate_Relation_Input(this);
});
```

and for all of those i have separate function, here's an example of one:

```
function validate_Email_Input(el) {
    var $this = $(el);
    var input_groups = $this.parent();
    var isValid = true;
    $.each(input_groups , function(i){
        var inpg = input_groups[i];
        email_values = $.map($(inpg).children('input'), function(e,i){
            return $(e).val();
        }).join('');
        isValid = isValid && validate_Email(email_values, input_groups.parent().parent().parent());
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

I really want to learn how to write efficient code, Any Help Greatly apreciated...

I don't know if this helps at all. but what i'm trying to do is validate everything and have messages pop out for each specific field. This is my first really big project in jQuery and I thought i may as well show you all what im working on: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/36BLm/

sample of a valid ID: 85 0929 5266086

Comment: +1 for not wanting to become a programmer who's code ends up at http://www.codecrap.com !

Comment: You always may use "multiple" selector: `input.email, input.id, ...`.

Comment: For your first party you could just have one function for all of your `input` elements and delegate using its class name. For the second part, if each function is significantly different from each other, there is not much to substitute.

Comment: Thanks Simon, and I have tried the multiple selectors.. but how do i target a function based on the selector then?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be a much better place to ask these questions.

Comment: Thank you Juhana, didn't know about it, will definitely try that next time.

Comment: +1 @simon-andre-forsberg for intoducing me to codecrap.com!!

Comment: Hey Guys, There's so many answers, and they all probably are correct and who am i to pick one above the other i don't know what the best practice is.. help.. please

Comment: You can upvote any number of answers. If many answers are right, just pick the one that you like best, or that teaches you the most. Nobody will be offended.

Comment: There are existing solutions for form validation like http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/ . Also creating many functions is not bad in itself.

Comment: i know about the plugins, but i really want to learn.. But Thank you..

Comment: Well, look at the plugin source code, this is how you reduce the code in your view ;) (Ultimately you will end up with *more* code - at least in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the exact same thing as your first block of code:

```
$(document)
.on('blur', 'input.email', validate_Email_Input)
.on('blur', 'input.id', validate_Id_Input)
.on('blur', 'input.pass', validate_Pass_Input)
.on('blur', 'input.town', validate_Town_Input)
.on('blur', 'input.relation', validate_Relation_Input)
.on('blur', 'input.contact', validate_Relation_Input);
```

**Edit:** commenter Ian is right. In order for this to work you need to change the second block of code to:

```
function validate_Email_Input() {
    var $this = $(this); // This line has changed
    var input_groups = $this.parent();
    var isValid = true;
    $.each(input_groups , function(i){
        var inpg = input_groups[i];
        email_values = $.map($(inpg).children('input'), function(e,i){
            return $(e).val();
        }).join('');
        isValid = isValid && validate_Email(email_values, input_groups.parent().parent().parent());
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: No it shouldn't. The first parameter of a callback is not `this`, it's the `event`. `this` is just set inside of the callback, and they are passing it to the functions.

Comment: And there's still multiple callback functions. The point was reducing code, not a few lines...

Comment: You're absolutely right. I edited my answer to be correct. I don't know if it needs further reduction. It should not be slow in this state and it's very readable. I'd only argue the validation code needs some comments since I can't figure out at a glance what it does.

Comment: Also (as I pointed out in another comment) there is no word about using fewer validation functions. We don't know if the other validation functions have the same bodies, so we can't assume that.

Comment: No you're definitely right. If you look at the jsFiddle the OP has, there definitely isn't a way to reduce the validation functions since they are so different, so good point.

Comment: As soon as i change the code to that it no longer validates?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object mapping each field selector to its validator function, and loop from within a single event handler:

```
$(document).on('blur', function(e) {
    var validators = {
        'input.email' : validate_Email_Input,
        'input.id' : validate_Id_Input
        // etc
    };
    for(var field in validators) {
        if($(e.target).is(field)) {
            validators['field'](e.target);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this solution you need to create a function for each input... the user want to avoid it...

Comment: That's not clear in the question, I'm not sure. How could you have the same function validate both an email an a phone number?

Comment: They just asked about having less lines with `on()`. They may have a good reason for having separate functions

Comment: I agree. No word about fewer validation functions in the question. We would have to see the other functions to be able to tell if they could somehow be simplyfied.

Comment: if you guys are still keen, i would love to learn : http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/36BLm/

Answer (score 0):

To refactor it you can create a model:

```
var myInputsModel = [
    { a: 'input.email' }, // you can store all the information you want in the model...
    { a: 'input.id' },
    etc...
];
```

so then you got just one function for all of them:

```
$.each(myInputsModel, function(i, v) {
    $(document).on('blur', v.a, function() {
        // One function for all of them.
        mySingleFunction(this);
    });
});


function mySingleFunction(el) {
    var $this = $(el);
    var input_groups = $this.parent();
    var isValid = true;
    $.each(input_groups , function(i){
        var inpg = input_groups[i];
        email_values = $.map($(inpg).children('input'), function(e,i){
            return $(e).val();
        }).join('');
        isValid = isValid && validate_Email(email_values, input_groups.parent().parent().parent());
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: This is close, but I don't think every value should pass through `validate_Email` (inside `mySingleFunction`). You could probably store a reference in `myInputsModel` and pass that to the `mySingleFunction`...then call it instead of always calling `validate_Email`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh ye, I didn't see there is also validate_email there... so I think he need one more inner function there to validate correctly everything.

Comment: Or maybe is just enough a control there... but this is a very deep refactoring. Manipulating it a bit can be exactly what the user is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(e){
    var valid = 1;
    var error_msg = "";
    //validate fields here, if fails set valid to 0 and error_msg to whatever
    if(!valid){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(error_msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one approach.
Start by giving all of the html elements a common class, and use a data attribute for the value type

```
<input type="text" class="validate" data-value-type="town" />
```

Sample jQuery + javascript

```
// Make an object matching strings to functions
var functionMap = {
  email: emailFunction(),
  id: idFunction(),
  pass: passFunction(),
  town: townFunction,
  relation: relationFunction(),
  contact: contactFunction
}
function validate(element){
  // see if the attribute being checked against has a matching entry in functionMap
  if(functionMap[element.data('value-type')] !== undefined){
    // call the function if it's there
    functionMap[element.data('value-type')];
  }
}

$(document).on('blur', '.validate', function(){
  validate($(this));
}
```